# Using webkitdirectory to upload a directory, is it possible to filter out certain subdirectory folder prior to uploading?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to upload multiple folder and just want to ignore specific folder from reading its files 
example :-
 **0345** (root Folder)
            - ABB (sub folder1)
               - ASCII(sub folder1.1)
               - DATA(sub folder1.2)(This folder i dont want to read (bypass it while uploading))

I tried different hack but failed

below is the fiddle where you can try it

```
(https://jsfiddle.net/6jkm5ws3/33/)
```

Thanks !

Comment: The answer is "Yes," but this is not what you are looking for, probably? Try adding some details and example code, and it would be an amazing to check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: How can i achieve this @cyberskunk

Comment: 0345 (root Folder)
|-- .ABB (sub folder under 0345)
      |-- ASCII(sub folder under ABB)
      |-- DATA(sUB FOLDER UNDER ABB)(This folder i dont want to read (bypass it while uploading))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var validatedFiles = [];
let list = document.getElementById('listing');
list.innerHTML = 'Filtered ASCII files are:.<br>';
$("#file").on("change", function (e) {
    $(".loader").show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
    $.each(e.target.files, function(index, value){
        var str = e.target.files[index].webkitRelativePath;
        var arr = str.split('/'); 
        arr_exe = (arr[arr.length-1]);
        extension = arr_exe.split('.').pop();

        arr_sec = (arr[arr.length-2]);
        if ((arr_sec =="ASCII" ||  arr_sec =="ascii" ||  arr_sec =="Ascii") && (extension !="exe")) {
            validatedFiles.push(value); // Simplest case
            list.innerHTML += '<br>' + value.webkitRelativePath;
            var str = e.target.files[index].webkitRelativePath;
            var arr = str.split('/');
            arr_exe = (arr[arr.length-4]);    
            validatedFiles.push(arr_exe);
        }
    });
});
```

In above code I'm filtering the array and passing it in validatedFiles which I will pass for uploading.